# Running a c++ executable using qt5

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt5

I have created a Qt5 application with Visual Studio (2019). When I compile and launch the application, everything goes well but if I try to launch it by hand, in other words by double clicking on the .exe file and not by clicking on 'Local Windows Debugger', I get errors like:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaXza.png)

For the translation: "Unable to execute the code, because QtWidgetsd.dll is
not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
problem". I get 3 messages each time with `QtWidgetsd.dll`, `QtCored.dll`, `QtGuid.dll` that are missing.
So I copied the .dll from `Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019_64/bin` But another error appears:
[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTYAp.png)

I have been searching for a long time, reinstalling visual studio, changing the qt5 configuration in VS but nothing changes.
Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: You need to have all of the required dependencies in the application directory in order to run the application. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html talks about how to determine what those are and ways to deal with them.

Comment: For error #2 you you need to have a platforms folder in the same folder that has your application. In that platforms folder you probably need qwindowsd.dll for a debug mode executable since you are trying to run the debug application.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to test this right away, but I don't know where to find qwindowsd.dll ...

Comment: Indeed, it works very well, thank you very much for your precious help! Great day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

### First solution

Use `windeployqt` to copy all the required `dlls`. But I don't like this solution.

### Second solution

Use `Cmake` correctly to link the `dlls` you can do that by adding these lines to your `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED) # Add all used qt packages
target_link_libraries(CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME PUBLIC Qt5::Widgets) # Add all used libraries.
```